# Concatenate Surfaces

Tags: matlab, concatenation, surface

How do I for instance concatenate 4 surfaces which do not have the same dimensions?

Example:

Surface1 1000x3
Surface2 900x3
Surface3 500x3
Surface4 1000x3

Is there a simple and elegant way of doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This problem is too broad. Please provide a small numeric example of some inputs and expected outputs. Also what are the data types? Are you interested in interpolation? In image synthesis? Be sure to mention what you already tried.

Comment: Fixed it with [a;b;c;d...] but plotting the surface seems to be way over the top because we have too many data points.